# Как распечатать QPixmap в PyQT5, используя диалог печати?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, qpixmap

не до конца разобрался с PyQT5 Python 3. У меня есть переменная screen типа QPixmap, могу ли я её распечатать? В ней хранится главное окно программы, которое необходимо распечатать. Код программы прикладывать не вижу смысла, важен лишь принцип работы в таких случаях, заранее, спасибо!

```
def print_text(self):
    screen = self.grab()
```

Comment: Смысл есть всегда и во всем, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.